# django-environ: how to separate INSTALLED_APPS for dev and prod

Tags: django

I am using djano-environ for my settings

In django development i am planning to install django-extensions app which i need only in development. So what is the recommended way to use django-environ for prod and dev w.r.t INSTALLED_APPS

I have to add it to the INSTALLED_APPS.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
   # third party apps
    'django_extensions',
]
```

Now how to use django-envion's .env file which will pass INSTALLED_APPS

because i will have a different .env files for dev and prod

Answer (score 1):

I have separate **dev.py** and **prod.py** since I've config keys which are not applicable in both the environments.

If you've multiple cases like this a good option would be to create a **dev.py**

**dev.py**

```
from base import *
INSTALLED_APPS += ['django_extensions', ]
```

Else if this is a one off case, you can load additional app list from your env file.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
] + os.list('ENV_SPECIFIC_APPS')
```

**envfile**

```
.
.
ENV_SPECIFIC_APPS=django_extensions
```

Comment: I am looking with django-envion